# Java sort List of objects with a hierarchy alphabetically

Tags: java, sorting, recursion, hierarchy, comparator

I have an entity called `Item`. `Item` can have parents and children.

Each `Item` has the following methods:

- `getParent()` --> returns an `Item`
- `getChildren()` --> returns a `List<Item>`
- `isLeaf()` --> returns a `Boolean`
- `getName()` --> returns a `String`

Each level in the hierarchy is a level in a construction site, for example level 1 is House 1, level 2 is Floor 1, level 3 is Room and level 4 is Window.

I have a `List<Item` and I need to sort them like this:

- Item 1 (House 1 > Floor 1 > Room 1 > Bath)
- Item 2 (House 1 > Floor 1 > Room 2 > Basement)
- Item 3 (House 1 > Floor 1 > Room 2 > Door)
- Item 4 (House 1 > Floor 1 > Room 2 > Window)
- Item 5 (House 1 > Floor 2 > Room 1 > Door)

I think I need some kind of recursive function but I can't imagine how it has to be.

I've already researched for sorting objects with a hierarchy in Java but I don't find anything similar to my case.

I would appreciate any help and sorry if the question is not clear 100% but it is quite hard to describe.

Thanks.

Comment: Basically you want to sort the leaves then? I would imagine that you would sort when adding the elements to the house object and then do a depth first lookup of the leaves

Comment: What is an entity? You can't create a new class called `Object`. There is already an important class in Java called `Object` ;)

Comment: @flakes thanks for your comment but I don't think that's important and it doesn't add anything to the question. The real name of the "Object" is `Objekt` (Object in German). I omitted that detail to avoid confusing people with irrelevant information. If you feel happier I can rename `Object` to `Item`

Comment: You need to provide some code. It is unclear to me what is your implementation. Are all entities of type `item` (houses, floors, rooms) or are those different classes? Do they implement/extend `item` class?

Comment: When discussing class design/method implementation, having a class name is pretty crucial for communication! Further, you should be providing some code in your questions to show us at what point your stuck. Define as much of the solution as you can and you'll find that people understand your problem better and provide answers closer to what you expect. *As an aside, names like `Objekt` and `Item` are pretty opaque names for a class.. try something more meaningful (makes it obvious as to the actual purpose, `HouseNode`, `FloorplanTree`, etc). Good naming is paramount to clean maintainable code*

Answer (score 0):

It would indeed be recursive. The trouble is that a simple recursive compare would only work if the two nodes were on the same level.

```
// Same level compare
int compareSameLevel(Item item) {
    int c = 0;
    if (this.getParent != null) {
        c = compare(this.getParent(), item.getParent());
    }
    return (c != 0) ? c : getName().compare(item.getName());
}
```

But you could adjust the levels to find a common level and assume that the children go after the parent:

```
// Compare on any level
int compare(Item item) {
    Item thisItem = this;
    int thisLevel = thisItem.level();
    int itemLevel = item.level();

    for (int i = thisLevel; i > itemLevel; i--) {
        thisItem = thisItem.getParent();
    }

    for (int j = itemLevel; j > thisLevel; j--) {
        item = item.getParent();
    }

    int c = compareSameLevel(thisItem, item);

    return c != 0 ? c : (thisLevel > itemLevel ? -1 : 1);
}
```

This is just to give you an idea. It is not tested or compiled.

Answer (score -1):

Pseudo code: Try like this

```
    private static void printChildElements(List<Object> childNodes) {
    for(Object childNode : childNodes) {

        List<Object > childElements = childNode .....;
        if(childElements.size() > 0) {
            printChildElements( childElements);
        }
    }
```

Comment: The question is about sorting, not about printing the whole tree.